# How many swaps in a set of size n will ensure that the set is shuffled reasonably well?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, random

I'm implementing my own version of a shuffle method for shuffling a set of objects in a list. My implementation generates two (pseudo)random numbers and swaps the elements at these two indexes. Currently these swaps occur 1000 times, but this obviously isn't great for large lists.

My question, is there a way to find how many swaps should occur so that my list (of some size n) is shuffled reasonably well?

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain you need this implementation? It will never produce uniform distribution if $n \geqslant 2$ (as depending on $n$ all permutations will be either odd or even). There is [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm that generates uniform distribution in $n - 1$ swaps. If you need this implementation - how do you measure wellness of shuffling?

Comment: I second Fisher-Yates, it is the standard way to do this.

Comment: No, I don't need this implementation. This shuffle method is part of a small game I need to create for an assignment, where a requirement is to implement my own shuffle method. I thought that this would be good enough for my purposes, but the Fisher-Yates approach seems a lot better (and simpler). Cheers!

Comment: The Fisher-Yates algorithm is the way to go.  Nevertheless, you might be interested in the paper "Shuffling Cards and Stopping Times" by Aldous and Diaconis.  Pdf here: https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/aldous86.pdf

Comment: @awkward Thanks for that, I'll check it out